# Azure app deployment error: Resource doesn't exist

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I am new to Azure and I running problems after problems, but still I think I have come far. I created the credentials using this command:

```
 az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "myApp" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/{sub-id}/resourceGroups/{SomeRes} --sdk-auth
```

Copied and pasted at the secrets on github.
And then the previous tasks run well, but it fails at this task: `Run Azure webapp deploy action using azure credentials`

```yaml
      # Run dotnet build and publish 
      - name: dotnet build and publish 
        working-directory: ./myDemoApp
        run: | 
          dotnet restore 
          dotnet build --configuration Release 
          dotnet publish -c Release -o '/someDemoApp'  
           
      # Deploy to Azure Web apps 
      - name: 'Run Azure webapp deploy action using azure credentials' 
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2 
        with:  
          app-name: SomeDemoApp
          package: './myDemoApp/someDemoApp' 
       
      - name: logout 
        run: | 
          az logout
```

And it returns this error:

```
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Resource SomeDemoApp doesn't exist.
```

How can I configure it so that I can deploy this?

UPDATE:

Fixed the first error by creating the app, but now it fails to find the package and returns this error:

```
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: No package found with specified pattern: ./myDemoApp/someDemoApp
```

Where can I find this package location, or to which of my configuration is related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error simply means that you are trying to deploy your code to a web app, but haven't created a web app in Azure (Why it doesn't exist).

You can follow this tutorial from Microsoft to deploy your web app manually. (Make sure the web app name is exactly the same as what you have in your yaml) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=netcore31&pivots=platform-linux

Running your pipeline after deploying the web app should then work.

Once you become more comfortable with this approach, you can add Infrastructure as code to your yaml pipeline to automatically spin up you web up if it does not exist using ARM templates and the AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 task in your pipeline.

Comment: It could also mean that the account that's being used to deploy doesn't have sufficient access to the resource group/resources.

Comment: That link really helped, but now I get this error: `Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: No package found with specified pattern: ./myDemoApp/someDemoApp`, how can be this explained?

Comment: I had the same message. Resource doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment. What worked for me was adding the service principal with role contributor to the resource group.